# What is the range for alpha in window equations

Tags: window-functions

Alpha is used in many window functions e.g.

[image]

What is the range that alpha can take and is it the same across all uses of alpha in the equations? e.g.

[image]

Will any alpha still result in a stable result, e.g. between 0 and 1

Comment: if you have access to MATLAB or Octave or something similar, just pick a nice large $N$ and plot the `fft()` of those windows for a variety of different $\alpha$ around 1 or 5 or 10.

Comment: I'm writing window functions in C and am wondering if the range should be locked before processing?

Comment: It's a "shape factor" that can mean different things for different windows, so no single answer is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the window is of limited support, and the denominator can not vanish for any real $\alpha$, it yields a potentially valid window (finite area, finite power). Since is does not vanish on the interval, it can be inverted. It interpolates between a constant or uniform for $\alpha = 0$ and a discrete Dirac-like (or better Kronecker) window (for $\alpha = \pm \infty$). The $\alpha$ parameter drives the weights applied to the samples away from  the central sample. It  can be estimated from your sample-to-sample stationnary, or the resolution property you aim at.

[image: Family of Poisson windows]